# CSS & Image Files Are Blocked by Googlebot after Rendering

Tags: wordpress, seo, search-engines

When rendering my website in [Mobile-Friendly Test](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly/result?id=2QPXsD3LcxRqVpb-BGtCPA), I saw that my sites' CSS + Images are blocked.

[image: See This Screenshot]

[image: See This Screenshot]

The site is built on Elementor, there isn't a cache plugin.
I disabled all plugins and it's still the same.

**This is my robots.txt file:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: 
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Allow: .js 
Allow: .css

sitemap: https://www.carxpress.co.il/sitemap_index.xml
```

Any insights?

Comment: You don't need any of the `Allow:` lines in your robots.txt because you don't disallow anything.  I'd also expect wildcards in a couple of the lines like `Allow: *.js` if you actually needed them to allow your JavaScript files.

Comment: Are you sure that a plugin for your browser is not stopping them ?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the Mobile-Friendly Test CSS issues you can remove the `type="text/css"` from the CSS head tags and only keep something like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.example.com/styles.css">`.

Image errors are more because of this tool is time-specific while Google doesn't have a time limit. Many of the resources Google uses from its own cache while this tool fetches each resource from a fresh start. So you don't have to worry about it.

Also, if you have a lazy-loading for your images you can try to disable it.

Comment: Why would `type="text/css"` in the stylesheet link cause problems?

Comment: @mora Fe - Which tool are we talking about ?  And what makes you think that Google will wait endlessly?